# Who were these recent Wolverine bad guys who mimicked his healing factor/claws with tech?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification

This is Logan Wolverine (not the current female version), 616 universe, from somewhat recent comics (post 2010 I'm reasonably certain). This involved a group of bad guys who had nanotech-based healing factors and some sort of energy-based Wolverine-style claws created by some shady corporation or other. Looking for any identifying info or the issue numbers/storyline they appeared in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the 'Adamantium Men', a group of super-soldiers seen in **[Wolverine: Weapon X Vol 1, #1-5](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/][1]][1]Wolverine:_Weapon_X_Vol_1).**

- **Energy claws:** Check.
- **Healing powers:** Check.
- **Shady Corporation:** Check

[image]

Comment: That was them! Thank you.

Comment: @Flipscuba - [You're welcome](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/11/1108020b64cbfab5dade9bf9fff0e7a1f5584bf8cc9b10f721a72b439b3a338e.jpg)